# Can not run Delphi Android application directly onto the Android device

Tags: delphi, mobile, firemonkey

I want to test a Delphi Android application directly on the device. I connected the device and do everything, but when I run the app, an error displayed:

> Missing profile name: Unable to get a valide profile from environment
>   options file.

I have Windows 8 and Delphi Tokyo 10.2.
[image]

Comment: try to delete androidmanifest.xml file from the project and then build the project again

Comment: Have you enabled the development mode on your android device? If not your device will not accept any application from Delphi to be deployed to it. When this feature is disabled the only way to go and deploy or install an application from your computer to the mobile device is to use special mobile device management software like Lenovo Moto Smart Assistant in case of Lenovo tablets.

Comment: where cani found androidmanifest.xml because it was gray in the deployment tab ?, i searched it but not found !!

Comment: Better to use Delphi Berlin Update 2. It's more stable and less buggy.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. delete `androidmanifest.xml` file from the project
2. you will find it here :

> %your-project-folder%\Android\Debug

3. then build the project again

Comment: Delphi dosn't create this folders because can't build project.

Comment: did you try to `clean` the project ?

Comment: it's a Windows 8 problem!